# how to join 3 table wherehas eloquent using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, wherehas

for example I have 3 tables and that tables has a relation,

Table A

- id
- name

Table B

- id
- tableId_A
- tableId_C

Table C

- id
- name

i'm using table C but i want to search items by request name that have the same name as in table A using query eloquent
and this is the query, i'm using a laravel

```
$this->model->query()
            ->withWhereHas('tableB', function($query) use ($names) {
            $query->tableB->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$names}%");})
```

how to fix it using eloquent where has used 3 tables relation?

Comment: did you use `many to many` relation?

Comment: yes i have used eloquent many to many
this is the script:
```
    public function tableB()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(TableAModel::class, 'TableB', 'tableId_C', 'tableId_A')->where('TableA.status', CoreStatusEnum::ACTIVE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your relation name should be `tableA` not tableB.

```
public function tableA() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(TableAModel::class, 'TableB', 'tableId_C', 'tableId_A')
        ->where('TableA.status', CoreStatusEnum::ACTIVE); 
}
```

And your query goes like this..

```
$this->model->query()
    ->withWhereHas('tableA', function($query) use ($names) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$names}%");
    })
    ->get();
```